# jQuery.each() measuring width on iOS device

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, responsive-design

A problem appeared only on iOS Device.
I tried my code on Desktop, Laptop, Android Device and iOS Device.

However on iOS I am not getting results.

**Attaching `.each()` on a class `.table`**

Afterwards, checking each table with a class `.table` if its `outerWidth()` is larger then `.table-responsive` width. So since my website is responsive, some tables contain too much data and the only way to make it functional is to make them horizontally scrollable. This does work for any browser I tried, but not iOS device.

When I try to send an `alert()` from `.each()` function, I do get a response, but not when I add `alert()` into `if()` statement.

Not quite sure why ?

```
$(function () {
  $(".table").each(function () {
    if ($(this).outerWidth() > $(".table-responsive").outerWidth()) {
      $(".table-responsive").addClass("noSwipe");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: whether the script is executed in dom ready?

Comment: Edited, because it is just a small script from one file. It is executed when document is ready.

Comment: it looks like some issue with the paint flow.... can you move the script inside the dom ready handler to a timeout handler like `$(function () { setTimeout(function () {<your-script>}, 500) })

Comment: have you tried checking the values of `$(this).outerWidth()` and `$(".table-responsive").outerWidth()`? do they return the expected results?

Comment: Timeout doesn't really helps. As mentioned, it is loaded on DOM Ready and each is triggered. 
@AminJafari - I checked the results by `alert()` and it returns same dimensions of inner (scrollable) and outer (not-scrollable) element. Quite interesting... I am still unable to make it work.